# Pressing enter in form does not execute js function properly

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Django to create a form where users will have to enter their email to get notified in the future. I have added a js function to handle submiting the form, because I want to display a modal.

While clicking to submit the form behaves as expected, when I press enter it does not.

This is the view that handles the form:

```
def add_notify_email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NotifyEmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "error"})
    else:
        form = NotifyEmailForm()
    return render(request, "landing/home.html", {"form": form})
```

The html code for the form is below:

```
<form action="{% url "notify:notify_email_add" %}" method="post" id="notify_email_form_in_hero">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group" id="email_input_in_hero">
            <div class="input-group-addon" id="coming_soon_email_icon_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="email_icon_in_hero"></i></div>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode === 13){addNotifyEmailInHero()}" placeholder="If you want to get notified when we go live, please enter your email...." maxlength="255" required id="id_email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" id="notify_email_button_in_hero">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="addNotifyEmailInHero()" id="submit_notify_email_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-bell nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notify Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="coming_soon.js"></script>
```

When the button `submit_notify_email_in_hero` is clicked, the script `coming_soon.js` is executed:

```
function addNotifyEmailInHero(e){
    var notifyEmailForm = $("#notify_email_form_in_hero");
    var thanksModal = $("#thanks");

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/notify-email/add/',
    data: notifyEmailForm.serialize(),
    success: function(res){
               alert(res.status);
               if(res.status === "success") {                
                    thanksModal.modal('show');
                        }

                else {$("#id_email").val("");
                      $("#id_email").attr("placeholder", "Please Enter A Valid Email Address");
                        }
    }
})}


$("#id_email").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
       addNotifyEmailInHero();
}});
```

The form works perfecly by clicking the button, the issues come when you press enter to submit it.

If you press enter, from what I understand the function `addNotifyEmailInHero` is executed but instead of getting the json response and handle it, it just displays it: `{"status": "success"}`

**Update:**

I followed geebro's answer, leaving everything the except the suggested changes. This is by html code:

```
<div class="container" id="notify_email_container_in_hero">
    <form onsubmit="addNotifyEmailInHero()" method="post" id="notify_email_form_in_hero">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 input-group" id="email_input_in_hero">
                <div class="input-group-addon" id="coming_soon_email_icon_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="email_icon_in_hero"></i></div>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="If you want to get notified when we go live, please enter your email...." maxlength="255" required id="id_email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" id="notify_email_button_in_hero">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="submit_notify_email_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-bell nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notify Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="{% static "landing/js/coming_soon.js" %}"></script>
```

It seems to work, although I get an extra post request:

```
[07/Dec/2017 00:39:45] "POST /notify-email/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21
[07/Dec/2017 00:39:45] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 23016
```

Comment: proper way to do is preventing form submission using juqery and executing the ajax. onkeypress is not an elegant way.

Comment: How is this a Python / Django question actually ??? You'd have the very same problem with just any backend techno.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="addNotifyEmailInHero()" id="submit_notify_email_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-bell nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notify Me</button>
```

to

```
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"  id="submit_notify_email_in_hero"><i class="fa fa-bell nav-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Notify Me</button>
```

and change the opening form tag to

```
<form action="{% url "notify:notify_email_add" %}" onsubmit="addNotifyEmailInHero()" method="post" id="notify_email_form_in_hero">
```

It should work then

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and the weird behaviour remanins. I removed the action from the form tag and it worked correctly.

I suppose the action in form messed with the ajax call.